# regex manipulation and string substitution - alternative to sed

Tags: regex, string, bash

I have the following file

`cat file.txt`

```
ID      Location
MNS1    NC_000004.12:g.d.a144120555T>C;NC_001423.23:c.a144120513G<C
MNS2    NC_000142.12:g.a144120552C,N>D
MNS3    NC_000142.12:g.a144120559C>N
```

I would like to replace the input in this manner:

```
ID      Location
MNS1    NC_000004.12:144120555;NC_001423.23:144120513
MNS2    NC_000142.12:144120552
MNS3    NC_000142.12:144120559
```

I would like to remove everything but numbers that appear between `:` and `;`

For example, I tried:

`echo "NC_000004.12:g.d.a144120555T>C;" | sed 's/:[^0-9]*/:/g; s/[^0-9]*;/;/g; s/[^0-9]*$//g'`

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
NC_000004.12:144120555
```

Comment: All standard UNIX tools understand `\w` and `\d` as being the literal characters `w` and `d`. Some non-standard tools and tools with extensions to POSIX standards interpret one or the other of them as being shorthand for the POSIX character classes `[[:alnum:]_]` and `[[:digit:]]` (e.g. GNU awk accepts `\w` as such but not `\d`), which is what I assume you mean them to represent in  your question, but YMMV. There's really no good reason to not simply and clearly say "letter" or "digit" in your question, though, if that's what you mean.

Comment: It's not clear why `>C` and `>A` disappeared from your expected output, though, since it doesn't match what I think you mean by `I am trying to remove every \w or \w\. that occurs after : and \d{3}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Perl is an option for you:

```
cat file.txt 
ID      Location
MNS1    NC_000004.12:g.d.a144120555T>C;NC_001423.23:c.a144120513G<C
MNS2    NC_000142.12:g.a144120552C,N>D
MNS3    NC_000142.12:g.a144120559C>N

perl -ape 's/:\D+(\d+).*?(?=;|$)/:$1/g' file.txt 
ID      Location
MNS1    NC_000004.12:144120555;NC_001423.23:144120513
MNS2    NC_000142.12:144120552
MNS3    NC_000142.12:144120559
```

**Explanation:**

```
s/            # substitute
    :           # colon
    \D+         # 1 or more non digits
    (\d+)       # group 1,, 1 or more digit
    .*?         # 0 or more any character but bewline, not greedy
    (?=;|$)     # positive lookahead, make sure we have semi-colon or end of line
/             # with
    :           # colon
    $1          # content of group 1 (i.e. the digits)
/g            # end, global
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess perl is the best alternative

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick!

```
sed -i.bak 's/g\.//g; s/\w>\w//g' filename
```

for `(NC.*?):` concat, bit explanation about the end output will help , although this might work:

```
s/NC[0-9]?:/:/
```

Comment: gotcha! I was overthinking way too hard. I was initially gonna use this within awk, but I guess it's best pipe `sed` into `awk`

Comment: So I am trying to remove `g\.` which works. and then `\w>\w`

Comment: Many `sed` dialects do not support the Perl regex shorthand `\w`. You should easily find dozens of existing questions which explain the available workarounds, but try `[[:alnum:]]` for a start.

Comment: @user171558 piping sed into awk (or vice-versa) is never the best approach.